# What are the parameters set by the JRE installer in my linux machine apart from copying JRE files?

Tags: java, linux

I am writing a Java Swing application. I downloaded JRE for Linux platfrom from Oracle website and just bundled this JRE my application.

I have given a launcher script, in which I am referring the bundled JRE bin/java executable. So it works fine.

My question is, what is the difference between installing the JRE by downloading from the Oracle website and this procedure?

What are the extra parameters set by the JRE installer in my Linux machine apart from copying JRE files?

What are the environment variables set and what are the shared libraries copied? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on *how* you install.

First, I assume you are talking about Java 8, since later versions of Java don't come with a separate JRE.

For Oracle Java 8 installations for Linux, there is a choice of rpm or other package installers or the basic Linux manual installation. The latter is described [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml). As you can see from the documentation, it's just a simple tar.gz which you unzip/untar into a directory of your choice, and that's it. The same as your bundled JRE.

Answer (score -3):

if you want develop a application. you should download jdk, not jre.

jdk: java develop tookit

jre: java runtime.

linux has an old **openjdk**, but you can download **jdk** from oracle website. just download a **xx.tar.gz**, and untar it into:
/usr/java/jdk1.8xx

and set path:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export  JAVA_HOME  PATH  CLASSPATH
```

Comment: Good answer, but it does not relate to the question at all...